# While scraping a website for product information using beautifulsoup4 in python 3.6

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I did not get this how to scrape only the text, below is the code which I have written to scrape itemTitle and itemPrice I'm sorry if this looks stupid I'm just new to this.

> Input:

```
i_price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'_89yzn'})
i_name = soup.find_all('span',{'class': ['_2tW1I']} )

for name,price in zip(i_name, i_price):
  print(name)
  print(price)
```

> Output:

```
<span class="_2tW1I" data-aut-id="itemTitle">Wedding dress</span>
<span class="_89yzn" data-aut-id="itemPrice">Rs 4,000</span>
```

I just want the text to be shown otherwise its looking ugly.

Comment: you want the .text but this needs to be done on an element by element basis E.g. generate i_price as a list with i_price = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'_89yzn'})]

Comment: By *text only* do you mean only the contents of the tags i.e. `Wedding dress` and `Rs 4,000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
i_price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'_89yzn'})
i_name = soup.find_all('span',{'class': ['_2tW1I']} )

for name,price in zip(i_name, i_price):
  print(name.text)
  print(price.text)
```